# Echo php product title - Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, text, woocommerce, echo

I have a text that I want to dispay as a description on every single product page and I want to echo the product name in the fields.

Example: ''Buy this (product name) from our store. This is the best (product name) in the industry. By using this (product name) you save more.''

I used the epho function but it seems not to work properly.

```
<? echo woocommerce_template_single_title(); ?>
```

Could some one please help me with that issue, it will be verry appreciated

P.S.: I use WooCommerce and Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

you should use `<?php         ?>`

```
<?php echo woocommerce_template_single_title(); ?>
```

or

```
<?= woocommerce_template_single_title(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php 

$tittle = woocommerce_template_single_title();
echo $tittle; 

?>
```

Comment: Should it be inserted inside the post itslef or inside the php file?

Comment: Inside the php file

Comment: it's on any page you wish to show it, read the documentation https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/

Comment: The thing is that I want it to show on the long description for all products, but I don't find where the long description is stored in the woocommerce core, my guess is that it uses the description from the wordpress posts